# Python - change given directory one level above or below

Tags: python

is there a way to get one level above or below directory from the one that is given?
For example '/a/b/c/' directory was entered in a function.

So function would return:

```
lvl_down = '/a/b/'
lvl_up = '/a/b/c/d/'
```

I think you can do it using 're' module (at least with one level below directory), but maybe there is more simple and better way to do it without regex?

Comment: Isn't there a choice of where to "`lvl_up`" (the child directories)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have no idea, how the function should know, that you want to go in directory *d*:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os.path

def lvl_down(path):
    return os.path.split(path)[0]

def lvl_up(path, up_dir):
    return os.path.join(path, up_dir)

print(lvl_down('a/b/c'))   # prints a/b
print(lvl_up('a/b/c','d')) # prints a/b/c/d
```

Note: Had another solution before, but os.path is a much better one.

Comment: Wouldn't a solution involving the `os.path` module be a good idea?

Comment: I thought the question was more about string operations.

Comment: @SebastianWerk: yes, that's what `os.path` does.

Comment: +1 for os.path; BTW Aren't your directions reverse? Up usually means parent directory

Comment: Used the notation of the question. Thanks to Pedro and SilentGhost for os.path.

Comment: Yeah I suppose. I think I expressed wrongly:).

Comment: How would make it to work with path like '/a/b/c/'? I edited my question (forgot to add slash at the end of the string). With this approach it deletes last slash.

Comment: I tried to asign value to lvl_down (which would become from '/a/b/c/' to '/a/b/c'). Then I would do this thing again on saved value, but then it returns '/a/b'. How to make it return '/a/b/'. If there is not '/' at the end, it will give error that such path does not exist.

Comment: Well I suppose, I can later concatenate with '/' at the end. But that approach doesn't look very neat :)

Answer (score 3):

Methods for manipulating paths can be found in the modules `os` and `os.path`.

[os.path.join](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) - Join one or more path components intelligently.

[os.path.split](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.split) - Split the pathname path into a pair, `(head, tail)` where *tail* is the last pathname component and *head* is everything leading up to that.

[os.path.isdir](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir) - Return *True* if path is an existing directory.

[os.listdir](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) - Return a list containing the names of the entries in the directory given by *path*.

```
def parentDir(dir):
    return os.path.split(dir)[0]

def childDirs(dir):
    possibleChildren = [os.path.join(dir, file) for file in os.listdir(dir)]
    return [file for file in possibleChildren if os.path.isdir(file)]
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if the path given ends in a slash, you should always remove it with a slice. With that said, here's how to get the parent directory of a path:

```
>>> import os.path
>>> p = '/usr/local'
>>> os.path.dirname(p)
'/usr'
```

To go down, just append the name to the variable like so:

```
>>> head = '/usr/local'
>>> rest = 'include'
>>> os.path.join(head, rest)
'/usr/local/include'
```

Comment: Thanks for idea to remove last slash with slice (how I did not thought about that!:)). Anyway I tried it, but I don't get it why it still removes another slash too. I tried like this:

    `a='/a/b/c/'
     a=a[:-1]
     print a
     print os.path.split(a)[0]`

It returns: 'a/b'. Shouldn't it return 'a/b/'?

Comment: I get it, so it always removes slash at the end. So I should add '/' after removing child directory? Or is there a better way to do that?

Comment: Remove the slash once when taking input, if a slash exists. Call os.path.dirname() to get the parent directory. No need to add '/' if you use os.path.join() to join path segments. Read the Python online doc about these 2 methods.